# get rows from another mysql table depening on distinct value from another mysql table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, mysql6

I have two mysql tables.

UserInformation

[image: UserInformation]

and

referencelog

[image]

Now, most of the columns are not of interest. This is what I am trying to do:

1. Get the unique "created_by_user_name" from referencelog for a given level id. I am able to do it by following query, which returns 3 unique user_name.

> SELECT DISTINCT log.created_by_user_name FROM ReferenceScreenResultLog
> log WHERE level="1"

but I want to some how join this with UserInformation table, so I get the rows from UserInformation. As in I want the three rows from UserInformation table corresponding to these 3 unique user names I get from above query. The columne user_name in UserInformation table is connected with created_by_user_name column in referencelog table.

Comment: Right so now you have all the information you need. Just add the JOIN and then you can use the userinformation columns

Comment: I know, but thats where I am struggling, Not comfortable with mysql much

Comment: Thats why some kind sole spent hours ne Days writing a manual and someone else spent another few days writing tutorials and putting them on the internet for you to use. Once you have attempted to write some code, if it does not work, then bring it here and ask for help,

Comment: I am sorry but, I did attempt to write SQL query to find the distinct username from one table. I mentioned it in the question. Did you see that?

Comment: Please provide sample data if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the two table are joined  by usr.id = log.created_by
the you could use a join this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr.first_name, log.created_by_user_name 
FROM ReferenceScreenResultLog log 
INNER JOIN UserInformation usr on usr.id = log.created_by 
WHERE level="1"
```

or for all usr row content

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr.*, log.created_by_user_name 
FROM ReferenceScreenResultLog log 
INNER JOIN UserInformation usr on usr.id = log.created_by 
WHERE level="1"
```

Comment: Thats pretty much what I want. but is it possible to get whole row content from usr, instead of just first_name and created_by_user_name?

Comment: yes, I figured it out. Thanks for the help;